# How can I workaround PHP advanced_html_dom.php failure on ANSI characters?

Tags: php

Despite that advanced_html_dom.php https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for simple_html_dom.php, this

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
print(str_get_html("á")->innertext );
```

outputs á as expected, but this

```
include 'advanced_html_dom.php';
print(str_get_html("á")->innertext );
```

outputs Ã¡ as not expected.

It looks to me that Advanced HTML DOM is messing up on character encoding.

Anyone know a workaround, using advanced_html_dom.php? Revert to simple_html_dom need not apply :-)